# Syntax error or access violation: 1103 Incorrect table name

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, database

I am trying to migrate the table but it throws an error saying the table name is not valid, Idk why, I check my database there is not even any similar name table, I follow the tutorial and this is working for video guy and not for me. Is there any way to fix it? I'm using laravel version 9

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->longText('description');
            $table->tinyInteger('status')->default('0');
            $table->tinyInteger('popular')->default('0');
            $table->string('.meta_title');
            $table->string('.meta_description');
            $table->string('.meta_keyword');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('categories');
    }
};
```

> **Error**

```
php artisan migrate                               

   INFO  Running migrations.  

  2022_12_04_110615_create_categories_table ............................................................................................... 5ms FAIL

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1103 Incorrect table name '' (SQL: create table `categories` (`id` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `name` varchar(191) not null, `slug` varchar(191) not null, `description` longtext not null, `status` tinyint not null default 
'0', `popular` tinyint not null default '0', ``.`meta_title` varchar(191) not null, ``.`meta_description` varchar(191) not null, ``.`meta_keyword` varchar(191) not null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')
```

Comment: I guess it's the dots in `'.meta_title'`, `'.meta_description'` and `'.meta_keyword'`. Are those dots required? (Looks like those column could/should be in their own table)

Comment: probably the dots... Did you create the migration via php artisan make:migration ?

Comment: Yeah that . creating the mess its not required the txt file he show have the dots and I just copied them as it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because there is a `dot` before these columns

```php
$table->string('.meta_title');
$table->string('.meta_description');
$table->string('.meta_keyword');
```

the compiler will expect the table name before the dot, when there is nothing before the dot it will throw this exception